# Creating users with no password using ASP.NET Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity-2

I have been given the requirement to provide the ability to create users through the UI with no password. I am trying to accomplish this using ASP.NET Identity.

I am able to successfully create a user without a password using the `UserManager`'s `Create` method:

```
if (vm.ShouldHavePassword)
{
    userManager.Create(userToInsert, vm.Password);
}
else
{
    userManager.Create(userToInsert);
}
```

After the call to the `Create` method, the test user gets successfully saved into our `AspNetUsers` table. And when I do not provide a password, the `PasswordHash` column in our `AspNetUsers` table is set to `NULL`.

My issue is, I cannot login as the test user that does not have a password. The following is the method call that we use to validate a user's credentials:

```
result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

I attempted to login as a test user that has a `NULL` `PasswordHash` multiple times. To do this, I do not provide a password in our login form. As a result, a `NULL` password is passed into the `PasswordSignInAsync` method. The return value of this method call is always `SignInStatus.Failure`.

Using ASP.NET Identity, how can I configure my code to correctly authenticate user credentials when the credentials contain a `NULL` password, and the user in the database contains a `NULL` `PasswordHash`? Is such a thing even possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate and / or solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28110934/asp-net-mvc-identity-login-without-password

Comment: I've already seen that question. What he was asking was how can I log in as _any_ user without having to provide a password. What I'm asking is how can I login as a specific user that does not have a password saved in the database.

Comment: Understood. Did you try the code that he posted? FindByNameAsync and SignInAsync?

Comment: I certainly could use that code, but I would have to provide some logic to verify that this specific user's password in the database is set to NULL first, otherwise I would be able to login as any user without providing a password. And I don't want to have to provide that logic, because SignInManager already takes care of that for me.

Answer (score 14):

Yes you can. ASP.NET Identity Framework is fully customizable. Just override `PasswordValidator.ValidateAsync` and `PasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword` methods like this:

```
internal class CustomPasswordValidator: PasswordValidator
{
    public override async Task<IdentityResult> ValidateAsync(string item)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item)) return IdentityResult.Success;
        return await base.ValidateAsync(item);
    }
}

internal class CustomPasswordHasher : PasswordHasher
{
    public override PasswordVerificationResult VerifyHashedPassword(string hashedPassword, string providedPassword)
    {
        if (hashedPassword == null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(providedPassword))
            return PasswordVerificationResult.Success;
        return base.VerifyHashedPassword(hashedPassword, providedPassword);
    }
}
```

And set them like this:

```
    var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));

    manager.PasswordValidator = new CustomPasswordValidator();
    manager.PasswordHasher = new CustomPasswordHasher();
```

Answer (score 13):

Okay, what you need to do is find the user (`AspNetUsers` user) using your db context. After you have the user, you can check if their `PasswordHash` is null.
If yes, then just sign them in using `SignInManager.SignIn`.
If not, use `SignInManager.PasswordSignIn`.

example..

```cs
//alternatively, you can find the user using Email, Id or some other unique field
var user = db.AspNetUsers.FirstOrDefault(p => p.UserName); 
if (user != null)
{
    if (user.PasswordHash == null)
        await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, true, true);
    else
        await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, 
            model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I often need to create the first admin user of the system (usually myself) so that I can create more accounts for customers.

`UserManager<AppUser>.CreateAsync(AppUser user)` is the right one to call because you don't want to put your password in the code/source control.

The user account created by the method above doesn't have the `PasswordHash`, like what others had mentioned. Hence you can't log in.

What I would do is to get to the application site, and click "Forgot password" (since I have that logic implemented as well). It would generate a password reset token, and send an email to my email with the link I can create to go back to the application to reset my password.

Answer (score -5):

I don't think you can validate user without password. As a workaround: Instead of blank password, I'll recommend to use some Dummy/Common password from C# code, both while creating User and while validating credential

When creating user

```
if (vm.ShouldHavePassword)
{
    userManager.Create(userToInsert, vm.Password);
}
else
{
    userManager.Create(userToInsert, "someDummy123$");
}
```

When validating

```
result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, "someDummy123$", model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

Comment: If anything you'd create a cryptographically random password and send the user a password reset email. But there is no scenario where you should use a dummy password that is the same for all users.